# Jenkins - Put parameter in array

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In a declarative pipeline I want user will choose list of machines and then some action will be executed on them in parallel.
I have an extendedChoice parameter with multiSelectDelimiter: ','

When I go over the list with this code below I get the characters of node and not entire node, how can I fix it ?

```
 for (node in nodes) {
    echo node
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for (node in nodes.split(',')) {
   echo node
}
```